# How do I convert a time (string) from one timezone to another in Javascript Node.js

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone

I have tried to create a time converter, which converts an upcoming time (for example 2:00pm EDT) to another time zone (for example UTC). The upcoming time is stored in a string at first, and gets converted into a date (I'm not very good at using Dates) (`let date = Date.parse(time + ', ' timezone)`), but it gives either `Invalid Date` or `NAN`.
If someone knows how to convert a string containing the time into another timezone, please share it in the comments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Date.parse(time + ', ' timezone)` is seriously misguided, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use a dedicated Date/Time library, such as [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for this type of conversion.

We create a DateTime object in the desired timezone, in this case 'America/New_York' (this is more precise that the abbreviation EDT which is ambiguous).

The date can be converted to UTC using [DateTime.toUTC()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoutc);

```js
const{ DateTime } = luxon;

const dt = DateTime.fromObject( { year: 2022, month: 8, day: 5, hour: 14 }, { zone: 'America/New_York'} )
console.log('Time (in zone):', dt.toString());
console.log('Time (UTC):    ', dt.toUTC().toString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ZJuab/UnRq1muTChgrVxJhSgygmL2GMLVmSJN7pcBEqJ1dWPbqN9CiZ6U3HrcApTIJsLnMgXYBYgtVkJ8fWiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use `.toISOString()` method.

`new Date(time).toISOString()` it will automatically convert to UTC

Comment: How does this **reliably** parse a timestamp in one timezone and produce a timestamp for a different timezone? Why does the OP get *Invalid Date* or *NAN*? How does your code address that?